# Tornado: error: cannot add/remove handle - multi_perform() already running

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, tornado

I am using Tornado to make some async requests, and want to make a request each second. I'm doing so as such:

```
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
import tornado.ioloop

def repeat():
    HTTP_CLIENT.fetch(some_request, handle_response)
    threading.Timer(1, repeat).start()

AsyncHTTPClient.configure(max_clients=100)
HTTP_CLIENT = AsyncHTTPClient()
repeat()
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

This works for about a minute but then I get this error:

> Exception in thread Thread-29: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   ...
>
> error: cannot add/remove handle - multi_perform() already running

I know that this is resulting from the fact that the IOLoop and AsyncHTTPClient should only be accessed from the thread where IOLoop.start() is called.

So how do I schedule my repeat() function to always run on the same thread where IOLoop.start() is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tornado is not thread-safe, aside from [add_callback](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_callback). Don't use threading code to schedule a callback in Tornado; do this instead:

```
def repeat():
    HTTP_CLIENT.fetch(some_request, handle_response)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_timeout(timedelta(seconds=1), repeat)
```

Comment: Thanks! Gotta run but I'll check this later and accept it if it's good

Comment: Getting this error: pylint] E0602:Undefined variable 'timedelta'

Comment: Just need to `import datetime` and also it's `datetime.timedelta`

Comment: Hi @A. Jesse, thanks a lot! I tested this and repeat gets called once and ONLY once. So this is not going to schedule a call to repeat every second - just a one time call. Is there a way to schedule the callback repeatedly?

Comment: I've updated my answer to clarify: call "add_timeout" from within the "repeat" function itself.